# Restart PC Then Automatically Execute this step

Tags: file, batch-file, command

This is my bat file code:

```
@ECHO OFF 
set FolderPath="C:\ForSSSSetupNeed"

IF EXIST "C:\ForAFCSSetupNeed" setup.exe

IF NOT EXIST "C:\ForAFCSSetupNeed" ( 
    mkdir c:\ForSSSSetupNeed
    abc.bat
    ECHO GELLO
    shutdown -r /t 00  
    setup.exe
)
PAUSE
```

When `C:\ForSSSSetupNeed` file is absent, the batch file will create the `C:\ForSSSSetupNeed` file and restart my PC.

After the restart of my PC, I want to have it automatically execute the `setup.exe`

How can I do that?

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is create a [RunOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entry for that executable. You can use the reg command to create the key, e.g.

```
reg ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v Foo /t REG_SZ /d "C:\\mysetup.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could copy setup.exe to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`, make setup.exe copy itself to `%TMP%` then delete the copy in the startup folder.
A hack but should work

Comment: Setup.exe is my one develop software. After execute 'shutdown -r /t 00 ' this command my PC restart but step 9 means(setup.exe) comand does not execute .I want when my pc again open it execute step 9(Setup.exe)

Comment: Both file (bat file and setup.exe are in my CD)

Comment: Add the ollowing to your batch file